# App token is null in Podio API request

Tags: php, podio

The code below returns an `app` object from the Podio API.

```
$app = PodioApp::get( $app_id, $attributes = array() );
```

but the token field in the response is null. The user is authenticated server-side. How can I get the token field in `$app`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need special privilege for your API Client/Secret to get that. For normal API Client the token field will be empty. The increase of trust level needed for this operation is only granted to trusted companies and individuals, e.g. partners, and the verification is done by our customer care team, you can contact them by mail: support@podio.com.